# A better way to split a sequence in chunks with overlaps?

Tags: python, split, overlap

I need a function to split an iterable into chunks with the option of having an overlap between the chunks.

I wrote the following code, which gives me the correct output but that is quite inefficient (slow). I can't figure out how to speed it up. Is there a better method?

```
def split_overlap(seq, size, overlap):
    '''(seq,int,int) => [[...],[...],...]
    Split a sequence into chunks of a specific size and overlap.
    Works also on strings! 

    Examples:
        >>> split_overlap(seq=list(range(10)),size=3,overlap=2)
        [[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7], [6, 7, 8], [7, 8, 9]]

        >>> split_overlap(seq=range(10),size=3,overlap=2)
        [range(0, 3), range(1, 4), range(2, 5), range(3, 6), range(4, 7), range(5, 8), range(6, 9), range(7, 10)]

        >>> split_overlap(seq=list(range(10)),size=7,overlap=2)
        [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
    '''
    if size < 1 or overlap < 0:
        raise ValueError('"size" must be an integer with >= 1 while "overlap" must be >= 0')
    result = []
    while True:
        if len(seq) <= size:
            result.append(seq)
            return result
        else:
            result.append(seq[:size])
            seq = seq[size-overlap:]
```

**Testing results so far:**

```
l = list(range(10))
s = 4
o = 2
print(split_overlap(l,s,o))
print(list(split_overlap_jdehesa(l,s,o)))
print(list(nwise_overlap(l,s,o)))
print(list(split_overlap_Moinuddin(l,s,o)))
print(list(gen_split_overlap(l,s,o)))
print(list(itr_split_overlap(l,s,o)))

[[0, 1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6, 7], [6, 7, 8, 9]]
[(0, 1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4, 5), (4, 5, 6, 7), (6, 7, 8, 9)]
[(0, 1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4, 5), (4, 5, 6, 7), (6, 7, 8, 9), (8, 9, None, None)] #wrong
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6, 7], [6, 7, 8, 9], [8, 9]] #wrong
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6, 7], [6, 7, 8, 9]]
[(0, 1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4, 5), (4, 5, 6, 7), (6, 7, 8, 9)]

%%timeit
split_overlap(l,7,2)
718 ns ± 2.36 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%%timeit
list(split_overlap_jdehesa(l,7,2))
4.02 µs ± 64.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%%timeit
list(nwise_overlap(l,7,2))
5.05 µs ± 102 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%%timeit
list(split_overlap_Moinuddin(l,7,2))
3.89 µs ± 78.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%%timeit
list(gen_split_overlap(l,7,2))
1.22 µs ± 13.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%%timeit
list(itr_split_overlap(l,7,2))
3.41 µs ± 36.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

**With longer list as input:**

```
l = list(range(100000))

%%timeit
split_overlap(l,7,2)
4.27 s ± 132 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
list(split_overlap_jdehesa(l,7,2))
31.1 ms ± 495 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%%timeit
list(nwise_overlap(l,7,2))
5.74 ms ± 66 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit
list(split_overlap_Moinuddin(l,7,2))
16.9 ms ± 89.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit
list(gen_split_overlap(l,7,2))
4.54 ms ± 22.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit
list(itr_split_overlap(l,7,2))
19.1 ms ± 240 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

From other tests (not reported here), it turned out that for small lists `len(list) <= 100`, my original implementation `split_overlap()` is the fastest. But for anything larger than that, `gen_split_overlap()` is the most efficient solution so far.

Comment: Do you actually need to build and return a list of lists? The pattern in `itertools` is to return an iterator of tuples, and evaluate lazily. Anyway, if this is **working code** that you think could be improved, maybe see [codereview.se].

Comment: An iterator would be fine as well

Comment: Actually it's not quite working, at least not as documented, because it only works on *sequences*, not iterables.

Comment: range() is an iterable

Comment: That's true, but not all things that are iterable support `[:size]`. Sequences are iterable, but not all iterables are sequences.

Comment: ["... `range` is actually an immutable sequence type, ..."](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yep! Good point. One more thing to fix!

Comment: This should probably be on Code Review, not SO.

Comment: I'd recommend you spend some time looking at e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes and think about how you could rewrite this to be more general. I don't think this is specific enough for SO, or working enough for CR.

Comment: I have corrected the description. Let's focus on sequences as input for now. It can return an iterable.

Comment: `seq = seq[size-overlap:]` is going to spend a lot of time making copies (given large sequences). Perhaps use indices instead and copy just what you need to yield.

Comment: When you say "quite inefficient," what do you mean?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I thought it was not good enough for CR as well, that is why I am here.

Comment: @NedBatchelder It takes too much time. I was looking for something faster. The memory usage may also be a problem in case of long lists (500k items or more). But those are my main inputs and I can't change it now. I can access a large quantity of memory (64 or 128 GB) so I wasn't worried about memory at first.

Comment: @alec_djinn well I must say i'm disappointed by the lack of performance the complete `itertools` (nwise) solution had. Nevermind

Comment: I'm glad I seem to be getting a good score, but just to be sure, did you wrap my function in a `list`? It is a generator, so just calling the function will only create the generator but not actually do the work.

Comment: @jdehesa good point. I didn't. I'll fix it and update the results

Comment: You should push the limits and test on a list of at least 100000 items. Your original code crunches a million item list for ~2 minutes on this machine.

Comment: @IljaEverilä running it now.. will update soon

Comment: @alec_djinn you don't need to type-cast using `list` in my first solution which will further improve it's performance ;) (for small lists), *(whereas second solution of mine will work well for huge list)*

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri I am quite puzzled by the results. Am I running the tests in the wrong way?

Comment: @alec_djinn Not completely wrong. In first solution of mine you should be doing the timeit of `split_overlap_Moinuddin(l,7,2)` instead of `list(split_overlap_Moinuddin(l,7,2))`, because it is already a list. And due to huge size, `list(...)` creates a new list increasing the time. However in mine second solution you need to type-cast it using `list(..)` as it yields `generator`

Comment: Wow, that's a nice unexpected result

Comment: @JamesSchinner Yes, really unexpected also for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes readability counts vs. speed. A simple generator that iterates over indices, producing slices gets the job done in reasonable time:

```
def gen_split_overlap(seq, size, overlap):        
    if size < 1 or overlap < 0:
        raise ValueError('size must be >= 1 and overlap >= 0')

    for i in range(0, len(seq) - overlap, size - overlap):            
        yield seq[i:i + size]
```

If you want to handle potentially infinite iterables, you just have to keep *overlap* items from the previous yield and slice *size - overlap* new items:

```
def itr_split_overlap(iterable, size, overlap):
    itr = iter(iterable)

    # initial slice, in case size exhausts iterable on the spot
    next_ = tuple(islice(itr, size))
    yield next_
    # overlap for initial iteration
    prev = next_[-overlap:] if overlap else ()

    # For long lists the repeated calls to a lambda are slow, but using
    # the 2-argument form of `iter()` is in general a nice trick.
    #for chunk in iter(lambda: tuple(islice(itr, size - overlap)), ()):

    while True:
        chunk = tuple(islice(itr, size - overlap))

        if not chunk:
            break

        next_ = (*prev, *chunk)
        yield next_

        # overlap == 0 is a special case
        if overlap:
            prev = next_[-overlap:]
```

Comment: `itr_split_overlap()` doesn't return the correct result

Comment: I was so deeply involved with `zip` that my mind* didn't thought of doing the direct slicing (+1)

Answer (score 4):

### If it is must to meet the criterion of the chunk size (and discard remaining chunks from end not meeting the chunk size criteria)

You can create you custom function using [**`zip`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and a *list comprehension* to achieve this as:

```
def split_overlap(seq, size, overlap):
     return [x for x in zip(*[seq[i::size-overlap] for i in range(size)])]
```

**Sample Run:**

```
# Chunk size: 3
# Overlap: 2 
>>> split_overlap(list(range(10)), 3, 2)
[(0, 1, 2), (1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5), (4, 5, 6), (5, 6, 7), (6, 7, 8), (7, 8, 9)]

# Chunk size: 3
# Overlap: 1
>>> split_overlap(list(range(10)), 3, 1)
[(0, 1, 2), (2, 3, 4), (4, 5, 6), (6, 7, 8)]

# Chunk size: 4
# Overlap: 1
>>> split_overlap(list(range(10)), 4, 1)
[(0, 1, 2, 3), (3, 4, 5, 6), (6, 7, 8, 9)]

# Chunk size: 4
# Overlap: 2
>>> split_overlap(list(range(10)), 4, 2)
[(0, 1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4, 5), (4, 5, 6, 7), (6, 7, 8, 9)]

# Chunk size: 4
# Overlap: 1
>>> split_overlap(list(range(10)), 4, 3)
[(0, 1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4, 5), (3, 4, 5, 6), (4, 5, 6, 7), (5, 6, 7, 8), (6, 7, 8, 9)]
```

### If remaining chunks from the end not meeting the criteria of chunk size are also desired

If you want to display the chunks even if the doesn't meet the pre-requisite of the chunk size, then you should be using the [**`itertools.zip_longest`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) in Python 3.x (which is equivalent of [**`itertools.izip_longest`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) in Python 2.x).

Also, this is **variant to *yield* the values dynamically**, which is more efficient in terms of memory in case you have huge list:

```
# Python 3.x
from itertools import zip_longest as iterzip

# Python 2.x
from itertools import izip_longest as iterzip

# Generator function
def split_overlap(seq, size, overlap):
    for x in iterzip(*[my_list[i::size-overlap] for i in range(size)]):
        yield tuple(i for i in x if i!=None) if x[-1]==None else x
        #      assuming that your initial list is  ^
        #      not containing the `None`, use of `iterzip` is based
        #      on the same assumption
```

Sample Run:

```
#     v  type-cast to list in order to display the result, 
#     v  not required during iterations
>>> list(split_overlap(list(range(10)),7,2))
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: I like that one!

Comment: Though it doesn't return the expected result, with an uneven split. `list(split_overlap([0]*10,7,2)) ==
[(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)]` **!=** `[(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)]`

Comment: @JamesSchinner Correct, because the next chunk doesn't meet the pre-requisite of the size to be `7` in this case. After getting the first chunk, remaining elements will be `3` and with allowed over lap of `2`, elements eligible for second chunk are `5`. But since the required chunk size is `7`, it is skipped

Comment: I only mention it because, OP made the same comment about my answer. Easy fix though, `zip_longest`

Comment: @JamesSchinner In that case OP is wrong about the their comment. It is a expected behavior for the program based on the requirement mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is about as good as it will get, you need to poll the sequence/iterable and build the chunks, but in any case, here is a lazy version that works with iterables and uses a [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) for performance:

```
from collections import deque

def split_overlap(iterable, size, overlap=0):
    size = int(size)
    overlap = int(overlap)
    if size < 1 or overlap < 0 or overlap >= size:
        raise ValueError()
    pops = size - overlap
    q = deque(maxlen=size)
    for elem in iterable:
        q.append(elem)
        if len(q) == size:
            yield tuple(q)
            for _ in range(pops):
                q.popleft()
    # Yield final incomplete tuple if necessary
    if len(q) > overlap:
        yield tuple(q)

>>> list(split_overlap(range(10), 4, 2))
[(0, 1, 2, 3), (3, 4, 5, 6), (6, 7, 8, 9)]
>>> list(split_overlap(range(10), 5, 2))
[(0, 1, 2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5, 6, 7), (6, 7, 8, 9)]
```

Note: as it is, the generator yields one last incomplete tuple if the input does not produce an exact number of chunks (see second example). If you want to avoid this remove the final `if len(q) > overlap: yield tuple(q)`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using

```
itertools.izip(...)
```

which is good for large lists, because it returns an iterator instead of a list.

like this:

```
import itertools
def split_overlap(iterable, size, overlap):
    '''(iter,int,int) => [[...],[...],...]
    Split an iterable into chunks of a specific size and overlap.
    Works also on strings! 

    Examples:
        >>> split_overlap(iterable=list(range(10)),size=3,overlap=2)
        [[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7], [6, 7, 8], [7, 8, 9]]

        >>> split_overlap(iterable=range(10),size=3,overlap=2)
        [range(0, 3), range(1, 4), range(2, 5), range(3, 6), range(4, 7), range(5, 8), range(6, 9), range(7, 10)]
    '''
    if size < 1 or overlap < 0:
        raise ValueError('"size" must be an integer with >= 1 while "overlap" must be >= 0')
    result = []
    for i in itertools.izip(*[iterable[i::size-overlap] for i in range(size)]):
        result.append(i)
    return result
```

Comment: You code does not produce the correct output. Try `print(split_overlap_Aviad(list(range(10),7,2))`